# When and how did Sirius get a new wand?

Tags: harry-potter, sirius-black

Chapter 22 of *Order of the Phoenix* contains this alarming line (emphasis mine):

> "*That’s right,*" said Sirius encouragingly, "*come on, let’s all ... let’s all have a drink while we’re waiting. Accio Butterbeer!*"
> **He raised his wand** as he spoke and half a dozen bottles came flying toward them out of the pantry

To memory, this is the first time that he is shown with a wand and it is widely presumed that his old one was snapped after his arrest. So, how did he - a very wanted man - get a new wand that suits him?

Comment: Travel is near-instantaneous in the Potter universe. Probably one of his buddies traveled to Diagon Alley and picked one up. Five minute job

Comment: @Valorum -- Also possible that the OotP keeps a few spares around.